# Elastic collision with one moving object hitting a stationary object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, velocity, collision

In an elastic collision, I understand that momentum is conserved and kinetic energy is conserved. If billiard ball of silver (with velocity $v_{(Ag)}$ impacts a stationary billiard ball of aluminum, I am trying to calculate the velocity of the aluminum ball after the collision, $v_{(Al)}$. After an elastic collision, the impactor is at rest and the impactee has the motion.

Using momentum, $= m \cdot v$

$$m_{(Ag)} \cdot v_{(Ag)} = m_{(Al)} \cdot v_{(Al)}$$

Assuming silver is 4x denser than aluminium, then using momentum, the aluminium ball should have velocity

$$v_{(Al)} = 4\cdot v_{(Ag)}$$

But if we use kinetic energy, $1/2 m \cdot v^2$

$$\frac12m_{(Ag)}\cdot v_{(ag)}^2=\frac12m_{(Al)}\cdot v_{(Al)}^2$$

$$v_{(Al)}^2=\frac{m_{(Ag)}}{m_{(Al)}}\cdot v_{(Ag)}^2$$

$$v_{(Al)}=\left(\frac{m_{(Ag)}}{m_{(Al)}}\right)^{\frac12}\cdot v_{(Ag)}$$

$$v_{(Al)}=2\cdot v_{(Ag)}$$

Somewhere I have lost some neuron connections in my brain because I cannot resolve this conflict. This is a perfectly elastic collision so both momentum and kinetic energy should be conserved.

---

I have read multiple threads including:

[When is energy conserved in a collision and not momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93971/)

[How to calculate velocities after collision?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91003/)

[How can I calculate the final velocities of two spheres after an elastic collision?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/599278/)

[Calculating new velocities of $n$-dimensional particles after collision](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/598480/)

[Velocities in an elastic collision](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/602734/)

[Summation of the velocities before and after an elastic collision](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/511971/)

Comment: If you throw a ping pong ball (head-on) against a heavy led ball (with the same radius),  what will happen?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the subscripts to make them a look a bit more nicer and upvoted this question. Hope your neurons get reconnected with the answer(s) to this question :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the objects have different masses, then there isn't a way to start the collision with object 1 moving and object 2 at rest and then end the collision with object 1 at rest and object 2 moving while also having the collision be elastic. You have over-constrained your system, and so you will find contradictions like the one you found here.

Using the equations from [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/602738/179151) in one of your linked questions, if we are setting $v_{A,f}=v_{B,i}=0$, then we end up with the system of equations
$$0 = \dfrac{m_A - m_B}{m_A+m_B} v_{A,i}$$
$$v_{B,f} = \dfrac{2m_A}{m_A+m_B} v_{A,i}$$

Which you can see is only consistent if $v_{A,i}=v_{B,f}=0$ for $m_A\neq m_B$ (which is the case of no collision), or if $m_A=m_B$.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to flesh out your answer. I actually preferred your initial answer which was more hint-like. It forced me to go back and do the formal analysis setting the initial momentum of the whole system, m1v1, equal to the momentum of the system after the collision, m1v1' + m2v2'. Doing the same for kinetic energy and combining equations gives the final equations in the linked answer.

Comment: it gets really interesting at 1)relativistic velocities when the mass is a function of velocity or 2) when the collision has elastic and inelastic character.

Answer (score 1):

If a small mass collides elastically with a larger one which was at rest, the smaller one will bounce back, not stop.

Answer (score 0):

You say...

```
 After an elastic collision, the impactor is at rest and the impactee has the motion.
```

That is only true if the masses of the two balls are equal. Clearly they will not be equal if one is made of silver and the other aluminium.